# PhpBB how to change post url

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, seo, phpbb3

I'm trying to change PhpBB (v 3.0.12) post urls in a Seo Oriented Way.

When a use create a new post ( post "**Test**" ) the generated url is similar to this one below:

`http://phpbb.local/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2`

I want to change the post' url in this way.

`http://phpbb.local/posts/test.html`

or something similar.

Is it possible ? Do i have to install any plugin ? I don't find anything about in the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

use http server rewrite ?   for example : 
apache rewriterule or nginx proxy.

Comment: How can i bind `http://phpbb.local/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2` with `http://phpbb.local/posts/test.html` whit an Apache Rewrite Rule?